# Подключение автоприёма с Perfect Money

Tags: php, хеширование

Здравствуйте товарищи, тут мне дали задачку интересную которую я сам почему-то не могу решить, и прошу у вас помощи. Есть форма:

```
<form action='https://perfectmoney.com/api/step1.asp' method='POST'>
        <input type='hidden' name='PAYEE_ACCOUNT' value='UXXXXXXX'/>
        <input type='hidden' name='PAYEE_NAME' value='Store'/>
        <input type='hidden' name='PAYMENT_ID' value='$id'/>
        <input type='hidden' name='PAYMENT_AMOUNT' value='$priceUsd'/>
        <input type='hidden' name='PAYMENT_UNITS' value='USD'/>
        <input type='hidden' name='STATUS_URL' value='http://5wmr.net/perfectmoney/status.php'/>
        <input type='hidden' name='PAYMENT_URL' value='http://example.net'/>
        <input type='hidden' name='PAYMENT_URL_METHOD' value='POST'/>
        <input type='hidden' name='NOPAYMENT_URL' value='http://example.net'/>
        <input type='hidden' name='NOPAYMENT_URL_METHOD' value='POST'/>
        <input type='hidden' name='SUGGESTED_MEMO' value='active'/>
        <input type='submit' name='PAYMENT_METHOD'value='Оплать>
    <input type='submit' name='PAYMENT_METHOD' value='Оплатить'>
    </form>
```

После нажатия на оплатить, нас перекидывает на сайт Perfect Money там мы оплачиваем, и потом Perfect Money отправляет в файл status.php данные об оплате, файл status.php выглядит так:

```
<?php
define('ALTERNATE_PHRASE_HASH', 'код');

$string=
      $_POST['PAYMENT_ID'].':'.$_POST['PAYEE_ACCOUNT'].':'.
      $_POST['PAYMENT_AMOUNT'].':'.$_POST['PAYMENT_UNITS'].':'.
      $_POST['PAYMENT_BATCH_NUM'].':'.
      $_POST['PAYER_ACCOUNT'].':'.ALTERNATE_PHRASE_HASH.':'.
      $_POST['TIMESTAMPGMT'];

$hash=strtoupper(md5($string));

if($hash==$_POST['V2_HASH']){
   mail("example@test.ru", "ewwefef", "Good");
}else{
   mail("example@test.ru", "wqdwqwqdwqd", $string); 
   mail("example@test.ru", "wqdwqwqdwqd", "HASH: " .$hash ." + " .$_POST["V2_HASH"]); 
}
?>
```

Так вот, беда в том что ХЭШИ разные и не знаю как сделать так чтобы выполнился код:

```
mail("example@test.ru", "ewwefef", "Good");
```

Помогите пожалуйста, уже третий день мозг ломаю...

Comment: как-то несолидно их сайт выглядит, доки в формате doc и прочее... я думаю вы должны посчитать хэш так как описано в документации или [здесь](https://perfectmoney.com/acct/samples/sample_status.txt)

Comment: Я так и делаю, не получается...

Comment: Ну обратитесь к ним саппорт.

Comment: Уже 4 дня не отвечают(

Comment: Если на их стороне все верно, то Вы могли ошибиться только с ` ALTERNATE_PHRASE_HASH'`

Comment: Нет, я его скопировал из поля в аккаунте.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно, проблема уже решена, но здесь ничего не написано по этому поводу, поэтому вот мои 5 копеек:
У меня проблема была в том, что в настройках платежки (на сайте perfect Money) в поле "Альтернативная кодовая фраза" было пусто и соответственно хэши не совпадали, а не заметил я это изначально потому, что хромятина автоматически в пустое поле подставила логин в перфекте и я думал, что это и есть кодовая фраза. А так код, представленный выше, правильный, только, зря сообщение об ошибках убрали, из них я и нашел проблему. Дефолтные сообщения об ошибках можно взять здесь https://perfectmoney.is/acct/samples/sample_status.txt

И да, забыл в представленном коде неправильно формируется ALTERNATE_PHRASE_HASH, нужно так:

```
$altHash = strtoupper(md5('Альтернативная кодовая фраза'));
define('ALTERNATE_PHRASE_HASH',  $altHash);
```

Answer (score 1):

В документации кодовая фраза `ohboyi’msogood1`
MD5 хеш должен быть `725A03FE3D9C44DC88601BB3F22420A9`
Такой результат дает функция PHP

```
strtoupper(md5('ohboyi’msogood1'))
```

Такое же преобразование упомянуто в [документации](https://perfectmoney.is/acct/samples/sample_status.txt).

Такой же результат и на Java:

```
MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(s.bytes).encodeHex().toString()
```

А в документации результат `67C305DCE49D430D540FCB3D6D2E13B0`
Так что что-то тут не так.

Answer (score 0):

В форме не вижу input TIMESTAMPGMT. Или вы забыли написать?

Comment: Оно передаётся POST параметром от Perfect Money.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно просто проверить ALTERNATE_PASSPHRASE в настройках на сайте PerfectMoney. Там в разделе про API есть тулза для проверки хэшей, вводишь все данные и она показывает правильный, с ним и нужно сравнить.

У них правда документация и поддержка никакующие. На днях пользователи стали жаловаться, что оплатили, а мой сайт говорит, что нет. Тоже грешил на неправильные хэши, но оказалось, PM стала отправлять уведомления с нового айпишника, IPv6. Но не всегда, только иногда. Логики не нашёл. В документации пусто. Добавил 2a00:d880:5:bb4:77:109:141:170 в белый список в обработчике - проблема исчезла. 21 век, прогресс, блин.